# How far in advance is it recommended to book flight tickets?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, bookings

Ok so I know that rule of thumb for booking flight tickets is 'earlier the better' but I am not sure how far in advance should the action be taken.
I have seen many cases where the min. prices at say 4 months before travel dates are higher than 3 months before, this I believe is primarily due to a new flight route being added or some complex airline thingy beyond me but this almost always happens. Also let me know if this is common or I am mistaken here.

So I am asking what is the time line that I should draw untill I look for better deals and book the flight eventually. I have to travel in last week June and return around 1 week Aug, I am open to changes in travel dates by 1 week in both direction and both ways.

Comment: The rule of thumb is certainly *not* the earlier the better, though they are almost guaranteed to go up rather than down within about 21 days of departure. The price of a seat on a flight shifts constantly these days. You can find some historical data on when prices may spike for a particular route using Bing Travel or the like, but airlines constantly adjust their algorithms to maximize revenue. If you think the current price is reasonable, book it.

Comment: It depends a lot on which route, what time of day ('rush' hours for example are relatively stable), airlines, and seasons (Christmas can be all over the place, for example).  However, we have a fantastic question that covers this theory to some extent, which I'm marking this question as a duplicate of (failing that, it'd be closed as too broad - see [faq]), and hopefully that'll be of some use.  The best rule of thumb generally is - if you can afford the current price and are ok paying that, book it.

Comment: and of course it depends heavily on the urgency to travel at a specific time and date to a specific destination. If I MUST be in at SEATAC on 3 September 2013 at 07:15 but can't take earlier flights than the one closest before that arrival because of whatever that I know will be a factor and I know that now, I'd best book now as the flight may well be full if I book later.